# Playing stacked videos

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I have multiple imageview subviews getting stacked based on my incoming data.  Basically all these subviews are either set to an image or a video layer based on my incoming data.  The problem i have is playing videos. i can play the first video in the stack but every video after that is just the sound of the first video.  How can i play each accordingly?

the views are navigated through with a tap event like snapchat.  see below:

```
@interface SceneImageViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *videoUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer;

@end

@implementation SceneImageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.mySubviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.videoCounterTags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int c = (int)[self.scenes count];
c--;
NSLog(@"int c = %d", c);
self.myCounter = [NSNumber numberWithInt:c];


for (int i=0; i<=c; i++) {

    //create imageView
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; // <--- This is very important
    imageView.tag = i;                        // <--- Add tag to track this subview in the view stack
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    NSLog(@"added image view %d", i);


    //get scene object
    PFObject *sceneObject = self.scenes[i];


    //get the PFFile and filetype
    PFFile *file = [sceneObject objectForKey:@"file"];
    NSString *fileType = [sceneObject objectForKey:@"fileType"];



    //check the filetype
    if ([fileType  isEqual: @"image"])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        //get image
        NSURL *imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:file.url];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            });
        });

    }

    //its a video
    else
    {
        // the video player
        NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:file.url];

        self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileUrl];
        self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

        self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
        //self.avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        self.avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
        [imageView.layer addSublayer:self.avPlayerLayer];

        NSNumber *tag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1];

        NSLog(@"tag = %@", tag);

        [self.videoCounterTags addObject:tag];

        //[self.avPlayer play];
    }



}



UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.screen];

[self.screen addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


}


 - (void)viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

NSLog(@"touch!");

[self.avPlayer pause];

int i = [self.myCounter intValue];
NSLog(@"counter = %d", i);



for(UIImageView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {

    if(subview.tag== i) {

        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

if ([self.videoCounterTags containsObject:self.myCounter]) {
    NSLog(@"play video!!!");
    [self.avPlayer play];
}

if (i == 0) {
    [self.avPlayer pause];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}


i--;
self.myCounter = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];


NSLog(@"counter after = %d", i);





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Brooks Hanes said is correct you keep overriding the avplayer. 
This is what i suggest for you to do:

1. Add the tap gesture to the imageView instead of the screen (or for a cleaner approach use `UIButton` instead):

   ```
   UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
   [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; // <--- This is very important
   imageView.tag = i;                        // <--- Add tag to track this subview in the view stack
   [self.view addSubview:imageView];
   NSLog(@"added image view %d", i);
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:imageView action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
   [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
   ```

This way in your `viewTapped:` method you could get the tag of the pressed image like so: `gesture.view.tag` instead of using the `myCounter`.

2. To get the video working you could create a new `AVPlayer` for each video but that might turn quite expensive memory wise. A better approach will be to use `AVPlayerItem` and switch the `AVPlayer`'s `AVPlayerItem` when changing the video.

So in the `for` loop do something like this where `self.videoFiles` is a `NSMutableDictionary` property:

```
           // the video player
            NSNumber *tag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1];
            NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:file.url];
          //save your video file url paired with the ImageView it belongs to.
           [self.videosFiles setObject:fileUrl forKey:tag];
// you only need to initialize the player once.
            if(self.avPlayer == nil){
                AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:fileUrl];
                AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
                self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
                self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                    selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];
            }
            // you don't need to keep the layer as a property 
            // (unless you need it for some reason 
            AVPlayerLayer* avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
            avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

            CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];                
            avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
            [imageView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
            NSLog(@"tag = %@", tag);                
            [self.videoCounterTags addObject:tag];
```

Now in your `viewTapped`:

```
 if ([self.videoCounterTags containsObject:gesture.view.tag]) { 

  NSLog(@"play video!!!");
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[self.videoFiles objectForKey:gesture.view.tag]];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    self.avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem: item];
    [self.avLayer play];
}
```

Or use the `self.videoFiles` instead and then you don't need `self.videoCounterTags` at all:

```
 NSURL* fileURL = [self.videoFiles objectForKey:gesture.view.tag];
 if (fileURL!=nil) {    
     NSLog(@"play video!!!");
     AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:fileURL];
     AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
     self.avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem: item];
     [self.avLayer play];
 }
```

That's the gist of it.

Comment: okay, ill try this the only thing im hesitant of is that if the tap gesture can only get added once like last time that i tried to add it to all the image views

Comment: You did it! Awesome! I never thought of using AVAsset either.  Is there a way to still give you the bounty even though it expired?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the way you're setting up the myCounter variable. It is set one time and never changes until a view is tapped, and then it is set to the count of scenes, -1.

In addition, try looking at the way you're setting to the _avPlayer pointer var.  It's always being set, over and over, and it seems that in a for loop you'd want to be storing references instead of simply updating the same pointer to the value latest in collection of scenes.

Also, from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerLayer_Class/):

> You can create arbitrary numbers of player layers with the same AVPlayer object. Only the most recently created player layer will actually display the video content on-screen.

So, it's possible that since you're using the same AVPlayer object to create all these AVPlayer layers, that you're never going to see any more than one actual video layer work.

Comment: Well if you find a solution with code to this, then i'll give you that bounty